# Android: how to create lists under the charts in Achartengine?

Tags: android, charts, android-listview, achartengine, android-linearlayout

Android: Hi, I'm using AchartEngine to display charts in my App
I have tried different ways to display this charts with some lists under the chart in my app, but I haven't. I have no Idea about how to use these charts with defining layouts in xml. I'm able to display the graphs without using the xml layouts.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Harry.

Comment: Show the code that you are trying....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Achartengine is referenced in your project (or compiled if you are including the source) then you should see the view available in the eclipse layout designer.

Just drag the view onto your layout.

Alternatively you can dynamically create your layout however this will require a little extra work and research

Answer (score 1):

AchartEngine has a class `ChartFactory` which is used for creating views or intents.

So, possibly you can set the view returned at desired place in the xml.

This way you can create a xml, here I have a LinearLayout that will contain my Graph.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in Activity class you can show the Graph by getting the id of LinearLayout and adding view to your LinearLayout. In the `onItemClick()` of the ListView show the Graph.

```
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = Bar_Chart.getBarDemoRenderer();
    linear_layout.removeAllViews();
    View mView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, Bar_Chart.getBarDemoDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    mView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
    linear_layout.addView(mView);
```

Comment: Hi Lalith, thank you for the Answer. Now I'm able to display the Charts and lists on the screen, but the size of the chart is decreasing on adding lists. I want the chart to display full screen and on scrolling down the lists has to display. Can you please help me with this. Thanks .
*here, I'm not using the listview declared in Xml. I'm creating list within the java file using Android simple list item 1.

Comment: I will insist you that you can show the graph in a seperate Activity if you are having more number of List Items. Also, you can check the answer if this worked for you, so that future user's can get benefit of it.

Comment: Welcome,also you can check the answer if this helped you finally, so that future user's can get the benefit from this answer...

Comment: yeah.. with  the answer you posted we can able to display the chart and list as well.  but as I mentioned the problem is with the size of the chart. the chart size is decreasing on adding the lists in the frame. And if we declare the lists under the chart layout , it is displaying the lists at the bottom of the screen and we can only able to scroll and view one list item at a time.

Comment: Its better to keep ListView on a seperate Activity and Graph on seperate activity.